# Javascript image editor library

Tags: javascript, image, plugins, editor

My friend and I have plan to build a web shop. One of the shop's main feature is the ability for the customer to design their own stuff. My friend took [polyvore website](http://www.polyvore.com/cgi/app) as an example.

The above link point to an editor page. In polyvore, the customer can drag and drop items from right-hand side to a 'canvas' in the left-hand side of the page. the image have simple handler for resizing, rotate and move.

This is the main feature that we want to achieve. I want to know if there are any free JavaScript library out there that provide these functionality? We don't need too advance stuffs, because the goal is not making something like online Photoshop application. The polyvore editor has most of the features that we need.

Comment: FYI, I prefer to use jQuery and jQuery-UI. But it don't close a chance for another framework, if the library only for that framework. I'm still waiting for more answers, while I kept looking. I also might consider making one, maybe using canvas, so if you have a good tutorial link, fell free to share it here, I'll vote up the good tutorial.

Thanks

Comment: Did you have any success?  I'd be interested to know what you found our or eventually used.  I am developing a similar app and although I'm leaning towards jQuery, I'd hate to rework something that's already been done....Thanks!

Comment: Hi Tom. The project itself has been put on hold, so I haven't search for the library again. Feel free to try the suggested libraries in the answers below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Pixastic](https://github.com/jseidelin/pixastic) has a simple Javascript image editor that uses Canvas.

Comment: A very low and simple javascript image editor: http://code.google.com/p/svg-edit/ (try the demo)

Comment: http://editor.pixastic.com uses canvas, not supported by IE

Comment: the project is cancelled, but pixastic seems promising. Maybe I'll try it later for the other projects

Comment: That link's down.

Comment: Link updated [padding]

Answer (score 8):

When it comes to transformations, fabricJS looks very good: http://fabricjs.com/

For effects, CamanJS seems to give a lot of control and also includes preset filters : http://camanjs.com/examples/

Answer (score 1):

If you develop your app using a full-featured JavaScript-based framework, like [Cappuccino](https://www.cappuccino.dev/) or [SproutCore](https://sproutcore.com/), this kind of lightweight image manipulation should be trivial to implement.

If you want a bit more flexibility with the site implementation, go with a smaller library like [jQuery UI](https://jqueryui.com/) or [Interface Elements](http://interface.eyecon.ro/) (that's a very incomplete list - there are tons of similar libraries around).

Answer (score 1):

### UPDATE 2021

**Darkroom** library has been **discontinued** and is **no longer maintained**.

---

<s>You can use **DarkRoom**. it's a simple and powerful image editor in the web. you can find it from the below link:
https://mattketmo.github.io/darkroomjs/.</s>

Answer (score 0):

This won't be a full answer, but should guide you. Ext-js has an object called Ext.Resizable, http://www.extjs.com/deploy/dev/docs/?class=Ext.Resizable,  you can apply it to any node and it will add handles for resizing it. This is not present in their core (jsquery-like) distro, you need the full distribution.

Rotating the images is quite more complicated as that is not supported in all browsers (webkit allows rotation through css). What I suggest is that you use a cross browser canvas library, like http://me.eae.net/projects/iecanvas/demo.html, that allows you to rotate images that are drawn on the canvas. However, you can't really combine the two that I've mentioned, I suggest you look at both of them for inspiration and roll out your own (unless somebody else finds a tool that does it already)