# image editing in php

Tags: php, image-processing

I want to have a system in my Joomla website where user can upload their image and create and design a product image by having the product template. For example the keychain needs to be design.
Can any one recommend is this possible with PhP? or I need some other platform to work on.

Thanks

Comment: I'd think that this would be easier to do with Javascript + HTML5 canvas. If you need to do it using PHP, you can read up on the existing PHP library [GD](http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php).

Comment: That would be possible with PHP (Using either the GD or ImageMagick extension), but it would probably take quite a bit of work if you need more than very basic editing. I would recommend that you first look to see if there is a Joomla extension that will do what you need. But to answer your question, it would be possible with PHP and JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done with GD or Imagemagick libraries for PHP.

Here is a sample script I wrote a while back to composite an image to a blank coffee mug using PHP and imagemagick. This should be very similar to what you're trying to do.

```
<?php

$im = new Imagick('image.jpg');
$mug = new Imagick('images/mug.png');

$im->scaleImage(300, 0);

$im->setImageFormat('png');
$im->setImageVirtualPixelMethod(Imagick::VIRTUALPIXELMETHOD_TRANSPARENT);
$im->setImageMatte(true);

$height = $im->getImageHeight();

$mug->compositeImage($im, $im->getImageCompose(), 80, 130);

header("Content-Type: image/png");
echo $mug;

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to provide a kind of graphic editor to users most likely you need a JavaScript implementation with PHP only handling the final result of it.

A common way to edit images with PHP is to use [Imagick](http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php), but your case doesn't really sound like that. This is more applicable to, say, cases when you need to resize all the uploaded image or to save them in a different format.

Comment: Actually I want to provide a graphic user interface to a user where he can design his own product with the given template

Comment: For this purpose JavaScript implementation is surely better than any (not necessarily PHP) server-side one. You might find this question relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1837921/javascript-image-editor-library