# Simple Javascript image editor for ASP.Net application

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, image

I'm doing a project on ASP.Net, whose task is to work with images.
So, I need to make the client part of whose tasks will include:
cropping, rotating, resizing.
I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1837921/javascript-image-editor-library/2070460) topic, but solution are too complicated for my problem (I have only 3 functions, not online version of Photoshop).
Could you give me a free solution for JS?
means that the sending result-image will be executed in Ajax.
Desirable,that solution should support Ie8+.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I've created a SimpleImageEditor for my Project.

I've used ImageAreaSelect for cropping and fc-ImageResizer for resizing.
For display I use Bootstrap 3.0.
https://bitbucket.org/Dr-klo/simpleimageeditor/

Answer (score 2):

It is not free, but Telerik has an [Image Editor 
for ASP.NET AJAX](http://www.telerik.com/products/aspnet-ajax/imageeditor.aspx).

Comment: +1. This is possible answer... also question itself if off-topic as it is about searching for libraries...

Comment: thanks, but I need a free version.And with support HD images )

Answer (score 1):

Full disclosure: I'm the author of StudioJS

**[StudioJS (MIT-licensed)](https://github.com/nathanaeljones/studiojs), ([see demo](http://studio.imageresizing.net/studio.html)) offers cropping, rotation, flipping, saturation, contrast, brightness adjustment, white-balance correction, and a number of image effects**.

It uses [ImageResizer](http://imageresizing.net) (of which I am also the author), to do the back-end work. The ImageResizer core, resizing, cropping, and rotation is free, but the image effects and adjustments require a license. Everything is on GitHub.

If you build your own solution, [check out my list of avoidable pitfalls](http://www.nathanaeljones.com/blog/2009/20-image-resizing-pitfalls). It can be a bit tricky.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a JavaScript free component to edit the image and convert it to base64 , then it will be ease to save this base64 as a server side code to physical file image

Javascript code :

```
http://cssdeck.com/labs/xnmcokhc
```

or by the same way there are many other JS options too in below link

```
http://www.jqueryrain.com/demo/jquery-crop-image-plugin/
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use an online editor such as [Pixlr](http://pixlr.com/editor/). I read it has an API so that you can set it up to work with your web application.It has the features you want, and also many more.

To have your own JS editor, I haven't found something ready available online but could make one of your own.

You could use the [imgAreaSelect](http://odyniec.net/projects/imgareaselect/) plugin (is used in WordPress) to make the client side part of the crop function. For the server side part, I have written this [article](http://codingstill.com/2011/07/creating-thumbnails-from-jpg-images-with-net/) some time ago to describe how a crop function works. You could adjust it to work with the imgAreaSelect plugin. If Pixlr doesn't suit you, let me know so that we can talk more about the second scenario.

Comment: thanks for answer. Pixlr is so complicated for my app.
I dont need multifunctional solution(remind: I just need 3 functions).
If in the near future I dont find a ready solution, I'll make my own, using your recommendations.